# I want to hide header in the static homepage that I am working on

Tags: headers, logo, static-website

I am creating a static homepage with SiteOrigin Page Builder, and I want to hide header (everything including logo), I want to add a bigger version of the logo in the static page. Link - http://idkwhereto.com

TIA.